Trouble with Dynamic Audio Playback in JavaScript Function
I've implemented a JavaScript function called showPianoProdigyOverlay(), designed to display an overlay with a virtual piano. Each key on the piano triggers a corresponding audio file when clicked. However, despite seemingly correct implementation, the audio playback doesn't work as intended. The issue lies in the playNote() function within the showPianoProdigyOverlay(). Despite correctly logging the data-note attribute of the clicked key, the getElementById() call to retrieve the corresponding audio element consistently returns null. This problem persists even after thorough debugging attempts, leaving me puzzled about the root cause. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
function showPianoProdigyOverlay() {
    characterSpeed = 0;
    inOverlay = true;
    const overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.className = 'overlay';
    overlay.innerHTML = `
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <div class="piano">
                <div data-note="C" class="key w"></div>
                <div data-note="Db" class="key b"></div>
                <div data-note="D" class="key w"></div>
                <div data-note="Eb" class="key b"></div>
                <div data-note="E" class="key w"></div>
                <div data-note="F" class="key w"></div>
                <div data-note="Gb" class="key b"></div>
                <div data-note="G" class="key w"></div>
                <div data-note="Ab" class="key b"></div>
                <div data-note="A" class="key w"></div>
                <div data-note="Bb" class="key b"></div>
                <div data-note="B" class="key w"></div>
            </div>

            <audio id="C" src="notes/C.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="Db" src="notes/Db.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="D" src="notes/D.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="Eb" src="notes/Eb.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="E" src="notes/E.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="F" src="notes/F.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="Gb" src="notes/Gb.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="G" src="notes/G.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="Ab" src="notes/Ab.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="A" src="notes/A.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="Bb" src="notes/Bb.mp3'></audio>
            <audio id="B" src="notes/B.mp3'></audio>
        </div>
    `;
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);

    const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.textContent = `
        *, *::before, *::after{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .overlay {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .piano {
            display: flex;
        }

        .key {
            height: calc(var(--width) * 4);
            width: var(--width);
        }

        .w {
            --width: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }

        .b {
            --width: 60px;
            background-color: black;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            margin-left: calc(var(--width) / -2);
            margin-right: calc(var(--width) / -2);
            z-index: 2;
        }
    `;
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

    const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

    console.log(keys);

    keys.forEach(key => {
        key.addEventListener('click', () => playNote(key))
    })

    function playNote(key){
        console.log("Note:", key.dataset.note);
        const noteAudio = document.getElementById(key.dataset.note)
        console.log("Audio element:", noteAudio);
        noteAudio.play()
    }
}

I attempted to debug the playNote() function within the showPianoProdigyOverlay() by logging relevant variables, such as the data-note attribute of the clicked key and the retrieved audio element using getElementById(). I expected the audio element to be correctly retrieved based on the data-note attribute. However, despite logging the correct data-note values, the getElementById() call consistently returned null for the corresponding audio element.

Which editor are you using? You have a malformed HTML block: <audio id="C" src="notes/C.mp3'></audio> [...]
The src attribute tries to close the first " with '
Try <audio id="C" src="notes/C.mp3"></audio> etc.
Your editor should highlight it.

Wow thank you so much! I'm using VSCode but as the html and css here are assigned dynamically using a javascript function it really just treats it like a string and doesn't highlight anything

You are right... I didn't notice the heredoc string. Now it works?
